# Delete selected checkbox items with select all validation

Tags: php, javascript

I've a list of items which are generated as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sacb" onchange="selAll();" title="select all"/>
  <?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    echo "<div><input type='checkbox' name='cb' value='$row[id]'>$row[item]</div>";
  }
?>
```

**Script**

```
function selAll(){
  var s = document.form.sacb;
  var t = document.form.cb;
  for(var i=0; i<t.length; i++){
    t[i].checked = s.checked;
  }
}
```

This is working well to select/deselect all checkboxes.

I want to submit this form where multiple/all selected items are to be deleted. But I'm not getting all selected checkboxes. I've searched and found that I need to replace my PHP code as:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='cb[]' value='$row[id]'>$row[item]
```

But as soon as I do this, the script fails to select all checkboxes. How to solve this problem? Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use dot notation to access elements with brackets in name so you'll have to retrieve them using the elements collection

```
function selAll(){
    var s = document.form.sacb;
    var checkboxes = document.form.elements['cb[]'];
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = s.checked;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get to update selected check box from below javascript

please add your code to select number of array selected by to get in simple javascript
i this example i have used jquery to just get array of checkbox and checking whether it is selected or not

```
var field, fields = $('.edit_user_notifi :checkbox'), i = fields.length;
        var notification_status = '';
        while (i--) {
            field = fields[i];
            if(notification_status == '')
            {
                if (field.checked) {
                    notification_status = field.id+'~1';

                } else {
                    notification_status = field.id+'~0';
                }
            }else{

                if (field.checked) {
                    notification_status = notification_status +','+ field.id+'~1';
                }else{
                    notification_status = notification_status +','+ field.id+'~0';
                }

            }
        }
```

just change little logic to get with simple javascript or if would be good to if you are using jquery.